# Lenovo P1 Gen 2 - Not working microphone on Manjaro Linux

Tags: linux, audio, lenovo-laptop, microphone

The microphone hardware seems recognized:

```
❯ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX8070 Analog [CX8070 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

But I test all the option of the alsa-mixer without any lucks, nothing is hearing my voice.

Is the hardware compatible with Manjaro Linux?

```
OS: Manjaro 18.1.5 Juhraya
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.3.18-1-MANJARO
```

Comment: The responsibility of compatibility for particular hardware lies with the manufacturer, not with volunteer support sites. We never get that kind of information from manufacturers. Instead, may I suggest you test with a LiveUSB from another distro, or the OS which came with the PC?

Comment: Sure I will. I ask this question in case somebody with the same hardware found the solution. Is not the right platform to do that?

Comment: Absolutely OK! You can also search in here as well as on the web for users with the same hardware you specified. BTW,I suggested using the alternate OS for testing because you're far more likely to find an answer by testing instead of by waiting for someone with the same hardware and OS combination to reply.